# Removing line numbers from `od`'s output

Tags: bash, od

Is there any flag to `od` to make it not output line numbers in the result?

Comment: It doesn't output line numbers (at least, none of my versions does). It starts each line with a byte offset into the file for that line. Is this what you want to remove?

Comment: Just try `od | cut -b9-` to only output from byte 9 on.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assuming you mean the byte offset, from `man od`

```
   -A, --address-radix=RADIX
          output format for file offsets.  RADIX is  one  of  [doxn],  for
          Decimal, Octal, Hex or None
```

so for example `od -An file`

Comment: The leading space is kind of annoying, but works (had already upvoted you long ago).

Comment: Came here to upvote @CiroSantilliTRUMPBANISBAD.  Boy is that space annoying - you mean you're gonna make me add a `| tr -d ' '` just to make this useful?  Don't they know programmers are lazy!